# Need help with set theory questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I was in the hospital for two weeks, and missed quite a bit of new material.
Unfortunately, the text book I've got and my friend's notes aren't very helpful in catching up with the missed material, and I've been reduced to ask for assistance...

1) Give an example of two groups A, B
So that A, B, A - B, A ⊕ B, A ∪ B are all different, but all sets have the same cardinal number(I believe that's the right name... Where ℕ = א‎0).
Prove the sets are different and both have the same cardinal number.

2) we will define ⊕ for cardinal numbers:
m, k are cardinal numbers(not specifically different). Define k ⊕ m in the following manner:
Let A, B be sets who correspond to |A| = k, |B| = m
We will define ⊕ to be the cardinal number of sets A, B:
k ⊕ m = |A ⊕ B|.

This definition is impossible. you must explain the issue, and show with an example why the definition is false.

The question isn't whether the definition matches the expectations, but whether or not there is a valid definition here.

Right, so I solved the first question after a very long.time trying to figure out what sets to use, and eventually went with Brian's advice, though I wrote it a bit differently:
I defined A as N and B as (Z-N) union {0}(Positives and negatives, with 0 in both sets).
I defined a 1-1 injective for (A-B) as n+1(0 -> 1, 1-> 2 etc.) and proved that thw cardinal for it is א0(though I just copied the proof for that feom the text book. felt a bit cheat-y, but we are allowed to even just write down the page in the book where the proof is found and it's considered valid)
The union for both groups is Z, which also comes to א0(again copied the solution from the text book).
This left me with just proving the cardinal for the symetrical difference, which I did using the same function I used for (A-B).
I injected it into N, and.proved the cardinality is identical, and that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For the first question, note that in order for the sets to be distinct but all have the same cardinality, they must be infinite. Show that if $A$ and $B$ are infinite subsets of $\Bbb Z$ whose intersection is finite and non-empty, they give you an example. (You may prefer simply to work with a specific example of such sets, though the general result is just about as easy.)

For the second question, what do we get for $1\oplus 1$ by this ‘definition’ if we take $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{1\}$? What if we take $A=B=\{0\}$? Does it really actually *define* $1\oplus 1$?

Comment: @Alexander: *Distinct* simply means that they're not equal, not that they're *disjoint*. If $A$ is the set of positive integers, and $B$ is the set of non-negative integers, then $A$ and $B$ are distinct sets, even though $A\cap B=A\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Yeah, I had a brain fart there for a moment...

Anyways, I'm feeling like a complete idiot for even asking further, but; I went with A = N and B = Z - {0}(textbook assumes 0 is a natural number). thus I get: A - B = phi for the simmetrical difference I get a union of phi and Z - 0 and for the union I get Z(with the zero included). Please tell me I'm on the right track?

Comment: And I just realized what an Idiot I am, because phi's cardinal is 0

Comment: Right, so several hours later, I went with: A = N B = (Z - N) intersecting {0}(ie negatives and 0). Proved all sets are aleph null except for the simmetrical difference one, for which I hold ~3/4 of the proof: simmetrical difference is the intersection of (A - B) and (B - A). An intersection is essentially a + sign when applied to cardinals, so I have aleph null plus something(the cardinal of B-A). I know it's also aleph null, but I'm not sure how to prove it... basically the way I built it B is just N*(-1), and the simmetrical difference is just Z without 0

Comment: @Alexander: (My apologies for taking so long; I’ve been offline for a couple of days.) I think that you mean $B=(\Bbb Z\setminus\Bbb N)\cup\{0\}$, and where you write *intersection*, you mean *union*. If so, that works fine. The symmetric difference is, as you say, $\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. The easiest way to verify that this is countably infinite is to find a bijection between it and a set that you already know is countably infinite. A bijection with $\Bbb Z$ is easy enough: define $f:A\mathbin{\triangle}B\to\Bbb Z$ by $f(n)=n$ if $n<0$ and $f(n)=n-1$ if $n>0$.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I meant, and I did exactly that. I was struggling with starting the solution, but thanks to you, and a few hours of smoke blowing.out my ears, I figured it out. Would like to confirm that I scored full marks on the assignment, and had you not pointed me in the right direction, I would've gotten 56/100. What's funnt.is that the solved question was posted yesterday,  and they did pretty much the same thing, only instead of creating Z composed of negative integers and 0, they just multiplied N by (-1), which accomplished the same thing

Comment: @Alexander: Glad it helped.